# Java Type Erasure, Generic Lists with Unchecked Assignment

Tags: java, generics, orm

Currently I'm writing a program where I have the following statement.

`List<BaseballStatistic> q = BaseballStatistic.FIND.where().eq("teamID",  "CHN").query();`

Here, it complains

Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List'. Reason: 'BaseballStatistic.FIND.where().eq("teamID", "CHN")' has raw type, so result of query is erased more...

I have an interface which looks like this

```
public interface Query<T> {
  ...
  List<T> execute();
}
```

then an abstract class that implements this interface

```
public abstract class AbstractQuery<T> implements Query<T> {
  Statement _statement = null;
  String _tableName;
  List<Clause> _clauses;
  Class<T> _type;

AbstractQuery(Class<T> type) {
  _type = type;
  _clauses = new ArrayList<>();
  _tableName = type.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
}

...
public abstract List<T> execute();
}
```

and finally a concrete implementation:

```
public class SimpleQuery<T> extends AbstractQuery<T> {

public SimpleQuery(Class<T> type) {
  super(type);
}
```

which houses the following .query function which looks like:

```
@Override
public List<T> execute() {
try {
  JSONObject jsonObject = Peanut.getClient().listStatistics(buildQuery());

  if (jsonObject == null || !jsonObject.has("results")) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  JSONArray columnNames = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");

  Map<String, Integer> columnNameMap = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length(); i++) {
    columnNameMap.put((String) columnNames.get(i), i);
  }

  JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

  List<T> ts = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray result = results.getJSONArray(i);
    T t = _type.newInstance();
    for (Field field : ObjectUtils.getFieldsUpTo(t.getClass(), PinotModel.class)) {
      if (field.getAnnotation(Column.class) == null) {
        continue;
      }

      Object obj = ObjectUtils.getDefaultValue(field.getType());
      String columnName = field.getAnnotation(Column.class).name();

      if (columnNameMap.containsKey(columnName)) {
        int idx = columnNameMap.get(columnName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(t, ObjectUtils.convertObject(obj, result.get(idx)));
      }
    }
    ts.add(t);
  }
  return ts;
} catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO: Throw Peanut specific error.
  Peanut.LOG.error(e);
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
}
```

It seems like here, at compilation, the returned list has lost it's type leading to the warning. If I change the original variable declaration to List the warning will leave, which makes sense.

Is there anyway around this or is there a larger fundamental issue at play?

EDIT:

Query Function that calls execute is here

```
 public List<T> query() {
   return _query.execute();
 }
```

And the relationship between SimpleQuery and BaseballStatistic.Find is as follows.

```
@Table(name = "baseballStats")
public class BaseballStatistic extends PinotModel {

  public static final Find FIND = new Find<BaseballStatistic (BaseballStatistic.class) { };
...
```

and PinotModel looks like

```
public class PinotModel {
  public static class Find<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;

  protected Find(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Query select(String... s) {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).select(s);
  }

  public Clause where() {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).where();
  }

  public Clause limit(Integer n) {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).limit(n);
  }

  public Clause top(Integer n) {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).top(n);
  }

  public Clause orderBy(String columnName, Order o) {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).orderBy(columnName, o);
  }

  public String tableName() {
    return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).getTableName();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Type erasure itself is a large fundamental issue, but that's a separate discussion entirely.  I'd just add a `@SuppressWarnings` to it because there is a sensible explanation for it.

Comment: Since the warning is really on the `List<BaseballStatistic> q = BaseballStatistic.FIND.where().eq("teamID",  "CHN").query();` I'm against putting `@SuppressWarnings` on it because this code is supposed to belong to a library eventually

Comment: You showed us the implementation and definition of `execute`, but shouldn't you show us `query()` instead?

Comment: Also, where do you instantiate `SimpleQuery`, or what is the relation between `SimpleQuery` and `BaseballStatistic.FIND`? And do methods like `where()` and `eq()` keep the regular type?

Comment: I edited it to add more information, but it's quite large so it's hard to include all the class informations

Comment: You don't need add that much information. For example the implementation of `execute` isn't important right now. What we need are method signature, return types and variable type. For example: `public static final Find FIND` why are you using a raw type of `Find` here? Here is another raw type `public Query select(...)` .. shouldn't your IDE warn you about this?

Comment: I wanted to use Find here so that I could pass in type information and so that when I write queries, I could do so without instantiating a  new "BaseballStatistic", i'm using IntelliJ and it hasn't warned me about it :/

Comment: That wasn't the question, the question was "why is it a raw type"? I.e why are you using `Find` there instead of `Find<BaseballStatistic>`. The same for `Query` as the return type of `select`. It is understandable that Intellij warns you about different types for `List<BaseballStatistic> q = BaseballStatistic.FIND.where().eq("teamID",  "CHN").query();`, because you've stopped carrying over the generic type while chaining the method calls. Thus Intellij doesn't know anymore what `query()` _really_ return at that point.

Comment: Sorry I was about to update my answer actually for that. I added those into my code just now but it still has the same. I'm assuming the reasoning this is occurring though is that I haven't passed down the type information somewhere down the chain of code?

Comment: "I'm assuming the reasoning this is occurring though is that I haven't passed down the type information somewhere down the chain of code?" That is correct. When your IntelliJ doesn't correctly warn you about such code, then go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections and then Java- > Code style issues -> Raw type can be generic. Activate that inspection. Then recheck your code for raw types/missing type information.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places that you're missing generic type parameters.

1. `BaseballStatistic.FIND`:

   `public static final Find<BaseballStatistic> FIND = new Find<BaseballStatistic> (BaseballStatistic.class) { };`
2. `PinotModel.select`:

   `public Query<T> select(String... s) {
     return new SimpleQuery<T>(type).select(s);
   }`

You're also missing type parameters on `PinotModel.where()`. `Clause` would also need a type parameter, including on the `AbstractQuery._clauses` field.